# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent because of res.?

Tags: node.js, rest, shopify

I'm trying to set up a method that is called with Shopify's webhook. I get the data and I'm able to store with a fresh server but I get "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent" returned in the console. I believe this is because I'm calling res twice. Any ideas on how to structure this better?

This is my method:

```
function createProductsWebHook(req,res,next) {
//if(req.headers){
//    res.status(200).send('Got it')
//     return next()
// }
 res.sendStatus(200) 
next()
const productResponse = req.body
console.log(productResponse)
const product = Product.build({
    body_html: req.body.body_html,
    title: req.body.title,
});
product.save()
    .then(saveProduct => res.json(saveProduct))
    .catch((e)=> {
        console.log(e)
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show where `createProductsWebHook()` is called from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This occurs because the middleware, `createProductsWebHook()`, is called first when a request is received, which then sends a `200` status code response, `res.sendStatus(200)`. Then in, in the same middleware function, `product.save().then(...)` is called. `save()`’s callback function attempts to send a response too – after one has already been sent by the very same middleware – using `res.json(saveProduct)`.

Key Takeaway

Middleware should not send the response; this defeats the purpose of middleware. Middleware's job is to decorate (add or remove information, i.e, headers, renew some auth session asynchronously, perform side effects, and other tasks) from a request or response and pass it along, like a chain of responsibility, not transmit it – that's what your route handler is for (the one you registered your HTTP path and method with, e.g., `app.post(my_path, some_middleware, route_handler)`.

Comment: You don't need to send the status code aside from `res.json(...)`; it handles the status for you.

Comment: Please show where `createProductsWebHook()` is called from if you need more help.

Comment: ah - ok thanks! I'm only calling it here: `.post(shopifyCtl.createProductsWebHook,function(req,res){
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })`                                                                                                    I read best practice is to send a response back to Shopify before doing anything with the data. That's why I was trying to send a code first.

Comment: Just an FYI, only middleware functions use the `next` callback parameter. It doesn't make sense to use it on final route handlers. It's impossible to tell if your intent was to make `createProductsWebHook()` middleware, or a route handler since we don't know where it's called from and the function is doing contradictory responsibilities.

Comment: Okay, that information is key. That means that `createProductsWebHook` *is middleware.* You should not do *any* response handling in there then, i.e., do not call `res.sendStatus(...)` or `res.json(...)`. Instead, do that in your anonymous function (the third argument to your `.post(...)` code above. Remember, you don't need to call both in the function, because that will attempt to send the response *twice* -- not good -- `res.json(...)` sets the status when it sends the json to the client.